# I'm create dynamic year button using php for loop in shorthand ,How do i put active class in for loop

Tags: php

I am trying this here is my code all things are working but active "class" not working. I'm used short hand loop

```
$cur_year = date('Y');

$url = 'url_here';

$active = "($get_year == $i)?'active':''";

for ($i=2020; $i<=$cur_year; $i++) echo '<a href="'.$url.'/'.$i.'" class="btn btn-default '.$active.'">'.$i.'</a>';
```

Thanks

Comment: $active = ($get_year == $i)?'active':'';

Comment: thanks but not working because $i is for loop variable. and if i put $active above for loop $i is empty.

Comment: You need to put $active = ($get_year == $i)?'active':'' in For Loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correct variable name in comparison code as well as its syntax too

Also put comparison code inside loop

```
<?php

$cur_year = date('Y');

$url = 'url_here';
for ($i=2020; $i<=$cur_year; $i++) {
    $active = ($cur_year == $i)?'active':''; //its $cur_year
    echo '<a href="'.$url.'/'.$i.'" class="btn btn-default '.$active.'">'.$i.'</a>';
}
```

Output : https://3v4l.org/ItEWY

Shorthand for loop : https://3v4l.org/PRiVt

Comment: Thanks Anant kumar singh it's working. 
Correct Answer for me:- "Shorthand for loop"